Laplacian of Heat Kernel on Riemannian manifolds with nonnegative Ricci curvature
I met a question in Theorem 3.3 in Ni's paper
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-75/issue-2/A-matrix-Li-Yau-Hamilton-estimate-for-Kähler-Ricci-flow/10.4310/jdg/1175266268.full
in which the author considered the comparison between the heat kernels on subvarieties and the origin manifold. More precisely, let $M^m$ be a complete Kahler manifold with nonnegative bisectional curvature, $V\subset M$ is an analytic subvariety of dimension $s<m$. Let $H(x,y,t)$ and $K_V(x,y,t)$ be the heat kernels on $M$ and $V$. Then
(i) $K_V(x,y,t)\leq (\pi t)^{m-s}H(x,y,t)$;
(ii) $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{V}(\pi t)^{m-s}H(x,y,t)dA_V(y)\geq 0$;
I'm confused with one small step of the proof. Now we have shown that
$$
\left(\Delta^{(y)}_V-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\left((\pi t)^{m-s}H(x,y,t)\right)\leq 0.
$$
here $y\in V,x\in M$ and $\Delta^{(y)}$ is the laplacian operator w.r.t $y\in V$. The author claimed that integrating the formula above yields (ii) directly.
I wonder why here
$$
\int_{V}\Delta^{(y)}_V\left[(\pi t)^{m-s}H(x,y,t)\right]dA_V(y)
$$
is well-defined and nonnegative.
Remark.
Here the singularity does not matter since we can do justification on the validity of the integration by parts. So if $V$ is compact, the integration above is zero;
